# Firefox not accepting theme well

Tags: gnome-shell, macosx

You may be wondering why I have done this but, I wanted to it looks cool. I have now managed to make my ubuntu 18.04 installation look like macOSX 10.13-10.15. The problem I'm facing is firefox doesn't seem to use the close, minimize and maximize icons at all instead use something random.
[With title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Icz9.png) [With out title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZlrK.png) Chrome seems to work fine, which is annoying since I only use firefox.
To fix it I have to turn on the title bar, which I don't want to do. Also if I'm downloading a file it doesn't look like the theme. [downloading something from firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKJeq.png) (This is not important but would be nice to fix.)

---

Here is the tutorial I used: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/make-ubuntu-look-like-mac-5-steps Thank you if you can help.

Comment: I see that too. Without the title bar, the min/max/close buttons are "different". I don't know of a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DKBose and other people who need a fix for this. I managed to fix this by installing firefox ubuntu edition. Just uninstall the firefox you had previously and do

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

This should work and theme should work with firefox.

Here is mine working:
[image: Let me know if the image doesn't show]